# Electron - Retrieving HTTP response headers from the BrowserWindow's loadUrl()

Tags: javascript, typescript, electron

I'm working on a test project hosted on a pc included in a SSO environment.
I'm actually pointing to a webpage hosted on a server inside this environment and I need to access the cookies (just got them) and the http headers of the request.
I studied the doc and it seems there isn't a callback function for the `loadUrl()` method nor an option I can use to get those headers.

link for the reference

https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window

`loadUrl` has a second optional parameter that is defined as an Electron.loadURLOption but it doesn't seem to be helpful

```
interface LoadURLOptions {
    /**
     * An HTTP Referrer url.
     */
    httpReferrer?: (string) | (Referrer);
    /**
     * A user agent originating the request.
     */
    userAgent?: string;
    /**
     * Extra headers separated by "\n"
     */
    extraHeaders?: string;
    postData?: (UploadRawData[]) | (UploadFile[]) | (UploadBlob[]);
    /**
     * Base url (with trailing path separator) for files to be loaded by the data url.
     * This is needed only if the specified url is a data url and needs to load other
     * files.
     */
    baseURLForDataURL?: string;
}
```

I'd appreciate any kind of help, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by registering a listener for the `onCompleted` or `onHeadersReceived` callback of the web context session's `webRequest` property, eg:

```
  const url = 'https://example.com/your/page';
  browserWindow.webContents.session.webRequest.onCompleted({ urls: [url] }, (details) => {
    // Access request headers via details.requestHeaders
    // Access response headers via details.responseHeaders
  });

  browserWindow.loadURL(url);
```

The `onHeadersReceived` is a little trickier as it requires invoking the passed callback in order to continue the page loading process.

Related [documentation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/web-request#webrequestoncompletedfilter-listener)